# How to manage layout on QDockWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting started with Qt and I have a project for my school. I want to make an interface that read a database of space-stuff and displays them.
Until now I can display the table in a list, and my actual goal is to show the details of the object when it is double clicked.

To do so I tried to open a second dock whenever the object is double clicked, and tried to make a layout inside the second dock to display properly the details.

The program successfuly open a new dock, but the widget are way too small and all packed in the upper left corner of the dock:
picture of the bug:

[image: picture of the bug]

I tried to do not use layout but only setWidget with QDockWidget, but it does only display the last widget.

Here is my code for the layout:

```
dock1 = new QDockWidget(tr("Caractéristiques de l'objet : "), this);
dock1->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
Nom_Objets = new QLineEdit(dock1);
layout->addWidget(Nom_Objets);
//dock1->setWidget(Nom_Objets);
Categorie_Objets = new QLineEdit(dock1);
layout->addWidget(Categorie_Objets);
//dock1->setWidget(Categorie_Objets);
Description_Objets = new QTextEdit(dock1);
layout->addWidget(Description_Objets);
//dock1->setWidget(Description_Objets);
setLayout(layout); 
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add several widgets to a QDockWidget then you must use a QWidget as a container:

```cpp
dock1 = new QDockWidget(tr("Caractéristiques de l'objet : "), this);
dock1->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock1);

QWidget* container = new QWidget;
dock1->setWidget(container);
QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);

Nom_Objets = new QLineEdit;
Categorie_Objets = new QLineEdit;
Description_Objets = new QTextEdit;

layout->addWidget(Nom_Objets);
layout->addWidget(Categorie_Objets);
layout->addWidget(Description_Objets);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out ! It works now ! You made my day !